# The influence of an increase in ATM's on the demand for central bank money

Tags: macroeconomics, central-banking

This is a question posed in Blanchard's book on Macroeconomics.

The question is simple. Consider an economy with a central bank (CB) and private banks. The demand for CB money is then determined by both the demand for currency $CU^d = cM^d$ by people where $c\in[0,1]$, and the demand for reserve by the private banks $R^d=\theta D^d=\theta(1-c)M^d$ where $D^d$ is the demand for deposits by people so given by the fraction $1-c$ of the total demand for money. Now call $H^d$ the demand for CB money. Then $H^d=[c+\theta(1-c)]YL(i)$.

Suppose now that the number of ATM's provided by the private banks increases which makes it easier for people to deposit money. What happens to the demand for CB money?

> My solution. The dependence of $H^d$ on the fraction of money in deposits is $$\dfrac{\partial H^d}{\partial (1-c)} = (\theta-1)YL(i)$$ which is a constant in $c$. So we can assume the demand for CB money is linear in $c$. If we assume that $\theta\in[0,1]$ then $\theta-1\in[-1,0]$ so $H^d$ depends negatively on $c$. If $c$ goes up, then $H^d$ goes down. (We also assumed $M^d>0$.)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution verification?

Comment: @HerrK. yes, I am. That, or if possible/necessary, comments on the solution.